# change background color in vue combobox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to change my combobox background or the text-color. Until now i have used `:class="{green : isInfinite}"`, but im not 100% sure about that. Is there another way? Im looking for a solution without the usage of scss. It looks like this:

[image]

```
<template>
      <v-combobox
          v-model="key"
          :items="items"
          :search-input.sync="search"
          hide-selected
          @change="getParameters(key)"
          return-object
          label="Search script"
          persistent-hint
          :class="{green : isInfinite}"
          class="ml-9"
          style="width: 75%;"
      >
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data: () => ({
  isInfinite: false
 })
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understood the question at all, but I prefer, in your situation:

```
:class="['some static claass', somethingIsTrue ? 'trueClass' : 'falseClass']"
```

Ternary operator is powerful tool in vue dynamic classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **selection slot** for that

```
<template>
  <v-combobox
    v-model="key"
    :items="items"
    :search-input.sync="search"
    hide-selected
    @change="getParameters(key)"
    return-object
    label="Search script"
    persistent-hint
    :class="{ green: isInfinite }"
    class="ml-9"
    style="width: 75%"
  >
    <template v-slot:selection="{ item }">
      <span class="txt-color">{{ item }}</span>
    </template>
  </v-combobox>
</template>

<style scoped>
.txt-color {
  color: green; /*changes the text color*/
  background-color: blue; /*changes the text background color*/
}
</style>
```

you can also add the class **conditionally**:

```
<span :class="{'txt-color': isInfinite}">{{ item }}</span>
```

Comment: Can i add a if condition? For example. If "isInfinite == true"; change the color to green?

Comment: yes, you can... I edited the answer check it out